# Избежание повторного закрытия и открытия элемента. jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Всем привет!

Вот код: http://jsfiddle.net/gFTfM/

Если открыть "Один" и потом еще раз нажать "Один", то соответствующий блок спрячется и снова покажется. Можно ли это как-то избежать? Я подумал, что можно добавить класс .opened к открытому элементу, только не знаю, как обрабатывать. Помогите, плиз

---

Простите, ссылку исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( $(this).hasClass('opened') ){
делай одно
} else {
делай второе
}
```

Comment: Посмотрев на ваш ответ, я понял, что не додумал совсем чуть-чуть))

Comment: Я рад, что сумел направить вас на правильное решение, но еще посоветовал бы заменить bind на on

Comment: @binliz А можно, так сказать, обосновать/объяснить, почему, пожалуйста?

Comment: наверное изза того, что функция устаревшая:{As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().}
Потому стоит пользоватся новой которая работает и при ajax загрузке.